# External hard disk Seagate of 4 TB does not appear on Windows Explorer

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, external-hard-drive

I bought an external Hard Disk of 4 TB of the brand Seagate, it looks like the following picture:

[image]

I bought it like one year ago, and one day when I was copying one video file of approximately 1 Gb, the operation suddenly stopped and I was not able to see the contents of the Drive. So, I tried to use Recuva, but the process for recovering the files was going to take days; therefore, I tried another program called Stellar and it managed to recover the files in shorter time. The disk was working fine after that, but in some occasions it was not recognized by my OS which is Windows 8.

Approximately, a month ago the drive does not appear on the Windows Explore. I have tried different solutions, but none of them are working. For example, I plug the disk into another usb ports and nothing happened, the cable is working just fine and the disk only has its light stable and does not goes on and off.

Also, I when I enter into the disk manager, it seems that the driver appears, but it is in hidden devices like in the following picture:

[image]

I tried to delete the driver, reboot and nothing happens. Also, the search for hardware changes and check to see if the there is a current drives is not working.
As a last resort I enter into diskpart:

[image]

However, the disk still does not appear. What can I do in this situation? Is it that the drive is dead? It is the first time that it happens to me with a Seagate drive, I have another one of 2 TB and it has like 4 years and is still working.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: That it's being recognised as a SCSI device should ring alarm bells. Best guess is the enclosure is failing.

Comment: If this is a 2.5 inch drive (laptop size),  I would try pulling it out of the existing enclosure and plugging it into a cheap 10 dollar USB adapter [like this one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B011M8YACM).  No external power required.  Even if it doesn't work, having an adapter like this is golden (at least to me).

Answer (score 0):

> However, the disk still does not appear. What can I do in this
> situation? Is it that the drive is dead?

The disk is likely dead.

Go to:  [Seatools](https://www.seagate.com/ca/en/support/downloads/seatools/seatools-win-master/)

Download seatools and test your disk.

> Step 1 Download the SeaTools for Windows file. Once the download
> starts, you will be prompted to either run the application, save the
> application or cancel the download. Click the Save button to save the
> application.
>
> Step 2 When you click on the Save button the Save As dialog will be
> launched. You may either save the application to your Desktop or to a
> folder of your choice.
>
> Step 3 After the SeaTools for Windows application has been downloaded
> and saved to the location you select, click on the SeaTools file to
> launch the Windows Installation Wizard.
>
> Step 4 Follow the instructions in the Wizard to complete the
> installation process.

.

> I have another one of 2 TB and it has like 4 years and is still
> working.

Disks and electronic gear in general can and do last different lengths of time.